# Modify Ms-Access Table Structure

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have an access table with certain structure and I want to copy it to a table with a different structure. The structure of the original table is:

```
col1-ddate(datetime)
col2-type(text)
col3-vvalue(number).
```

Each 3 rows have the same date. The type has repeated 3 values(sys, dia, pul).
Now I want to insert this table data to a new(temporary) table which has the following structure

```
col1-ddate(datetime)
col2-sys(number)
col3-dia(number)
col4-Pul(number)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your problem? Are you trying to create a table on MS-Access programmatically? Are you trying to transfer data from an in memory DataTable to another DataTable instance? Please clarify your question with the code you have written to solve this problem

Comment: Tables are existing already in Ms-Access. The second table is empty and I want fill it with data from the first one with c# and sql statements

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, a SQL query using conditional aggregation should achieve what you are looking for, grouping by the `datetime` field, e.g.:

```sql
select
    col1-ddate,
    max(iif(col2-type = "sys", col3-vvalue, null)) as col2-sys,
    max(iif(col2-type = "dia", col3-vvalue, null)) as col3-dia,
    max(iif(col2-type = "pul", col3-vvalue, null)) as col4-pul
into
    NewTemporaryTable
from
    YourTable
group by
    col1-ddate
```

Change `YourTable` to the name of your existing table.